# Mudar formato de uma data de yyyy-MM-dd para dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: java, java-ee, data

Tenho um `dataTable` onde exibo alguns dados porém a data está vindo no formato `yyyy-mm-dd` como eu faço pra mudar o formato dessa data para que eu consiga exibi-la corretamente em minha `dataTable`? E aonde eu faço essa formatação? No Bean ou no DAO?

Aqui está meu método que pega os dados do banco e preenche a `dataTable`:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void listar(){
        try{
            TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
            listaTarefa = tarefaDAO.listarPorUsuario(usuarioBean.getUsuarioLogado());   
        }catch(RuntimeException e){

        }
    }
```

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Tarefa> listarPorUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Tarefa> lista = null;
        try {
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Tarefa.listarPorCodigo");
            consulta.setParameter("usuario", usuario);
            lista = consulta.list();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        System.out.println("LISTA NO DAO:" + lista);
        return lista;
    }
```

Declaração das variáveis que são datas no Model:

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "data_inicio", nullable = false)
    private Date dataInicio;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "data_fim", nullable = false)
    private Date dataFim;
```

Quero exibir a data no formato `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: EU acho que já fizeram essa pergunta antes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize o **DateFormat**

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoDesejado = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String dataFormatada = null;

dataFormatada = formatoDesejado.format("sua data hora");
```

Caso precise converter utilizer o `.parse` dentro do `.format()`

**EDIT:** inclusão de outros exemplos para formatar @jsantos1991 [Exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423756/3861347)

**EDIT:** Converter String para Date, utilizando o modelo que citei acima.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dataString = dataFormatada //  <= sua data no formato de String; 

Date date = formatter.parse(dataString);
```

Comment: Outros exemplos para formatar a data http://stackoverflow.com/a/24423756/3792998

Comment: Beleza, eu entendo isso porem como posso formatar o valor novamente para Date mas nesse formado dd-mm-yyyy, porque minha variável é do tipo date e ela está na minha lista que preenche a dataTable

Comment: Eu consigo formatar a data para String já, porem quando vou passar ela pra Date novamente ela fica dessa forma: `Tue Jul 14 09:22:00 BRT 2015`

Comment: Editei lá para converter para Date

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo do que vai em `//passa sua data;` ?

Comment: @Math, coloquei

Answer (score 9):

Caso queira outra alternativa é possível usar o `<f:convertDateTime/>` dentro do `outputText` que fica no `dataTable`

Exemplo:

```
<p:column headerText="Data">
    <h:outputText value="#{var.data}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Boa alternativa @Techies

Comment: Muito Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou para mim.

```
minhaTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
             .format(meuObjeto.getDate()));
```

onde "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" é o formato que eu desejo e

"meuObjeto.getDate()" é a data que eu tenho atualmente.