# Como trabalhar com Datas convertidas

Tags: java

Saudações para todos,

tenho o seguinte algoritmo;

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

public class DataDirenciada {


    public static void main(String[] args) {  



        DateTime entrada = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 17, 30);  
        DateTime audiencia = new DateTime(2015, 2, 20, 14, 0);  

        int dias = Days.daysBetween(entrada, audiencia).getDays();  

        System.out.println("Quantidade de dias: " + dias);  

    }  

}
```

E esse é o resultado;

Quantidade de dias: 49

Na verdade não existe nada de errado com algoritmo, mas preste bem atenção a essas linhas de código;

```
    DateTime entrada = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 17, 30);
```

Como faço para DateTime receber uma data nesse formato 12/02/2015?

queria receber no formato mencionado e ao mesmo tempo ter o mesmo resultado da aplicação

eu sei que existe esse método abaixo;

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoBrasileiro = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Mas não estou sabendo usar.

Eu tentei fazer dessa forma, mas não deu certo, gerou um erro;

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

public class DataDirenciada {


    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        SimpleDateFormat formatoBrasileiro = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String dataStringInicio = "12/01/2015";
        String dataStringFinal = "14/01/2015";

            try {

                Date dataInicios = formatoBrasileiro.parse(dataStringInicio);
                Date dataFinal = formatoBrasileiro.parse(dataStringFinal);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        DateTime entrada = new DateTime(dataStringInicio);  
        DateTime audiencia = new DateTime(dataStringFinal);  

        int dias = Days.daysBetween(entrada, audiencia).getDays();  

        System.out.println("Quantidade de dias: " + dias);  

    }  

}
```

esse foi o erro;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "12/01/2015" is malformed at "/01/2015"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:780)
    at org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getInstantMillis(StringConverter.java:65)
    at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:175)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:257)
    at com.java.exercicios.DataDirenciada.main(DataDirenciada.java:28)
```

Comment: Talvez seria isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74558/3117 ?

Comment: Qual o problema com o SimpleDateFormat? quer converter de String para Date, Data.sql para Data.util, Data para String?

Comment: dá uma olhada, acabei de atualizar a minha postagem

Answer (score 1):

**wladyband**

O erro que ocorre está nessa parte aqui:

```
  DateTime entrada = new DateTime(dataStringInicio);  //<--mandou uma string
  DateTime audiencia = new DateTime(dataStringFinal); //<--mandou uma string
```

Isso porque o `DateTime` não aceita o padrão que sua `String` está como argumento (Os padrões que ele aceita [estão descritos aqui](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser())). Você criou ali as datas formatadas mas não as utilizou.

O `SimpleDateFormat` possui o padrão que você deseja, e ao dar um `parse` você pede pra ele lhe retornar um `Date` de acordo com o seu padrão.

Faça a seguinte alteração:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {  

        SimpleDateFormat formatoBrasileiro = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String dataStringInicio = "12/01/2015";
        String dataStringFinal = "14/01/2015";

            try {

                Date dataInicios = formatoBrasileiro.parse(dataStringInicio);
                Date dataFinal = formatoBrasileiro.parse(dataStringFinal);

               DateTime entrada = new DateTime(dataInicios.getTime());  
               DateTime audiencia = new DateTime(dataFinal.getTime());  

              int dias = Days.daysBetween(entrada, audiencia).getDays();  

               System.out.println("Quantidade de dias: " + dias); 

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Se isso não lhe servir. Dá uma olhada nos [construtores](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) da classe `DateTime`.

Comment: pela logica do seu algoritmo era para funcionar, mas ele está retornando a quantidade de dias como sendo 0 "zero"

Comment: Desculpa foi um erro de digitação, acabei escrevendo `dataInicios.getTime()` na data da audiência também, ao invés de `dataFinal.getTime()`. Corrigido

Answer (score 0):

Salve!

Isso resolve?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime entrada = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseDateTime("12/02/2015");
    DateTime audiencia = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseDateTime("12/03/2015");

    int dias = Days.daysBetween(entrada, audiencia).getDays();

    System.out.println("Quantidade de dias: " + dias);
}
```

Saída:

```
Quantidade de dias: 28
```

Se quiser modificar o padrão de entrada, basta seguir o padrão do `Formatter`. Ex: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`