# Fazer o objeto java.sql.Date ter o formato dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, data

Tenho um campo que é do tipo `String`, onde é digitada uma `data` no formato `dd/MM/yyyy` , estou convertendo para `java.sql.Date`, o resultado é: 2018-01-01.

O que eu precisava era obter a data no formato : `dd/MM/yyyy`, que seria :01/01/2018, mas precisa ser no formato `data`, não `String`, é possível?

O método que uso é este( na verdade simplifiquei para facilitar a quem possa ajudar podendo executar o código):

```
  public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dataInicialString = "01/01/2018";
        String dataFinalString = "14/05/2018";
        DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.sql.Date dataInicial = null;
        java.sql.Date dataFinal = null;

        dataInicial = new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse(dataInicialString).getTime());

        dataFinal = new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse(dataFinalString).getTime());

        System.out.println("DATAINICIAL:" + dataInicial);
        System.out.println("DATAFINAL:" + dataFinal);

    }
}
```

Comment: Outra duplicata: [Mudar formato de uma data de yyyy-MM-dd para dd-mm-yyyy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74558/28595)

Comment: Pra formatar, precisa transformar em string, no formato sql.Date ou ulti.Date você nao vai conseguir esse formato.

Answer (score 5):

Não há como alterar o formato, Date não tem formato.

Qualquer tipo/classe Date representa um instante específico no tempo, com uma precisão de milissegundos. Ela não tem qualquer formato, representa o número de milissegundos que decorreu desde 1 de janeiro de 1970 00: 00: 00.000 GMT.

A classe [java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) é um *wrapper* sobre [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), que permite que o JDBC identifique isso(java.util.Date) como um valor SQL DATE.

No código que colocou na pergunta, ao usar `System.out.println("DATAINICIAL:" + dataInicial);` o que está a ser feito é uma chamada ao método `toString()` que retorna uma string representado o valor no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`.
Se a utilização for essa pode sobrescrever o método para que ele retorne outro formato.
Tenha em atenção que a sobrescrita do método `toString()` pode trazer problemas já que "outros" podem depender da implementação padrão.